# How do I schedule a task at a random time via batch file?

Tags: batch-file, random, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I need to create a script that will run via a .bat file on Windows 7 machines.
The batch file will create a scheduled task that runs at a random time between 11am and 9pm on Sunday.
I am currently using this command that I know works but only at a specific time:

```
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /sc WEEKLY /d SUN /st 21:00:00 /ru ""
```

I want to randomize the time, so that I can run the same exact batch file across all 400 systems and have each of them get a different time within that range, so they aren't running the task at the same time. I don't care if a few of them get identical times, but I don't want all 400 running within the same few minutes.
Once I have a single batch file that works as intended, it would be pushed out to all systems and run one time to schedule that task.

Based on searching other answers here, I've tried using the following scripts, for now just trying to generate a random hour, but I am not getting the results I need:

Option 1)

```
set /a num=%random% * (21 - 11 + 1) / 32768 + 11
```

That command will generate a number within the correct range, but it's not really random, it seems to be based on the clock or something, because if I run it several times real quick, I get the same number and then it increments up as time passes, this wont work.

Option 2)

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%a in (1 1 20) do (
        call:rand 11 21
        echo !RAND_NUM!
) >> random2.txt

goto:EOF

REM The script ends at the above goto:EOF.  The following are functions.

REM rand()
REM Input: %1 is min, %2 is max.
REM Output: RAND_NUM is set to a random number from min through max.
:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto:EOF
```

That code, generates the random number correctly, but I don't know how to insert that number into the command like I want. I have tried replacing the ">> random2.txt" with the schtasks command, but it doesn't work, and I'm not getting and feed back to a log file to see why, I've tried it like this:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%a in (1 1 1) do (
        call:rand 11 21
        echo !RAND_NUM!
)
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st %RANDOM%:00:00 /ru "" > task.txt 2>&1
goto:EOF

REM The script ends at the above goto:EOF.  The following are functions.

REM rand()
REM Input: %1 is min, %2 is max.
REM Output: RAND_NUM is set to a random number from min through max.
:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto:EOF
```

So in that I've tried to use the %RANDOM% var as the hour component of the command.

The perfect solution would generate a random two digit number between 11 and 21 for the hours section and then a two digit number between 00 and 59 for the minutes section of the command with a colon in between them as required by the format of the command
so the time section of the schtasks command would look something like this:

```
%hour11-21%:%min00-59%:00
```

I hope I have given enough detail here, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :rand 1 1 dummy
call :rand 11 21 ret
call :rand 0 59 ret2
if %ret2% LSS 10 set ret2=0%ret2%
echo schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st %ret%:%ret2%:00 /ru "" > task.txt 2>&1
exit /b

:rand
setlocal
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
endlocal & set %~3=%RAND_NUM%
exit /b
```

Output:

```
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 11:00:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 16:7:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 17:46:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 19:35:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 13:54:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 14:51:00 /ru ""

U:\Scripts\Batch>RandomNumBetween.cmd
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st 21:48:00 /ru ""
```

Comment: Okay, strange, that partially works, the %ret2% variable works fine, but the %ret% variable only returns 12 as the result, I tried changing the call :rand numbers around for that line, and it always returns the minimum number +1

Comment: Nope, I did a straight copy and paste of your code into a batch file to test it, only tweaked it to have it append to the log file instead of just creating it, then I just executed it several times and looked at the repeated results in the log file.

Comment: That's odd. It works perfectly fine for me. I've tested it on Win7 x64 and win xp 32 bit.

Comment: check if you have `ret` assigned as an environment variable by typing `set r` from a command prompt. If so, set it to nothing with `set ret=` or closing the cmd prompt and opening a new one.

Comment: Okay, so not set as a variable already. And I even tried it on a clean VM just to be sure, and get the same result, hour stays the same, minutes are random. I also tried swapping the variables in the command, the %ret% variable always generates the same number. I then tried changing the name of the variable and set it to %ret1% and still it generates the same number.

Comment: Hmm. I'm stumped. It works perfectly fine for me as you can see. So, you just tested by creating a new cmd file and copied my code into and ran it from the cmd line like I did?

Comment: I copied it into Notepad, saved it as a .bat file, and then double clicked to execute the .bat file.  Side note, it looks like the hours variable is tied to the actual hour of the PC clock, when the hour changed 10 mins ago, the number generated by the variable increased by 1

Comment: Here is the code:
<code>
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set ret1=
    set ret2=
    call :rand 11 21 ret1
    call :rand 0 59 ret2
    echo schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /d SUN /sd 10/28/2012 /st %ret1%:%ret2%:00 /ru "" >> test.txt 2>&1
    exit /b

    :rand
    setlocal
    SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
    endlocal & set %~3=%RAND_NUM%
</code>

Comment: I found a small bug for numbers less than 10 that I fixed. Try running it from the CMD prompt instead of double clicking.

Comment: Ok. I get the same thing as you when I double click to run it vs running from the command line. I'm not sure why but will investigate further.

Comment: Ok, I know why it's happening and you're right, it does have to do with the system clock. Try the above code now.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you very much. Neat trick, since it screws with the first variable, you gave it a dummy one to screw up. Never would have thought of that.
Marking this as answered.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you schedule the task with `schtasks` and want the start time to vary every time the task is run, you can use this in a batch file:

```
:: Delay for up to 5 minutes (300 seconds)
set /A DELAY=%RANDOM% %% 301
ping /n %DELAY% /w 1000 localhost > NUL
```

You could use `timeout` instead of `ping` on Windows 7/Server 2008+.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:

```
set /a H=%random% * (21 - 11 + 1) / 32768 + 11

set /a M=%random% * (59 - 11 + 1) / 32768 + 11

H = Hour

M = Minute
```

then the scheduled task created with

SCHTASKS /Create /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SC WEEKLY /D FR /ST %H%:%M%

Greets,
Dan.

Comment: I'm a little confuses at to what each parameter does.  Can you break this down please?  And where are you calling the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Way too complex set /a commands. Use `%` = "remainder" which works like "modulo" for positive values. Even if it is counting "up" by only one digit in the short time, avoiding `/ 32768` makes it more random since I had that seemingly "not as random as I thought" effect too.
You need to use double `%` when using modulo in a .CMD, therefore we end up with triple `%`

```
:hour 11:00 until 21:00
set /a HOUR=%RANDOM%%%11+11
:minute 0-59
set /a MINUTE=%RANDOM%%%60
schtasks /create /tn "task" /tr c:\task.vbs /sc WEEKLY /d SUN /st %HOUR%:%MINUTE%:00 /ru ""
```